# Applying environment variable with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, gnuplot, popen

With gnuplot, I need to setup `export GDFONTPATH=${HOME}/fonts` for showing correct font. Or, I have this warning message "Could not find/open font when opening font "arial", using internal non-scalable font".

With Python, I try to automate invoking gnuplot with this code.

```
GNUPLOT=distutils.spawn.find_executable('gnuplot')        
my_env = os.environ
my_env["GDFONTPATH"] = '${HOME}/fonts'
p = Popen([GNUPLOT, config["file_path"]], shell=False, env=my_env)
p.communicate()
```

However, I have the warning message. What might be wrong? How to apply the environment variable in Python?

```
Could not find/open font when opening font "arial", using internal non-scalable font
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling the issue that you're using '${HOME}' directly. Try this instead:

```
my_env['GDFONTPATH'] = os.path.join(my_env['HOME'], 'fonts')
```

Comment: or `os.path.expanduser('~/fonts')`

Answer (score 1):

Let me propose a somewhat different solution:

The `pngcairo` terminal, which by the way produces much better results than the `png` terminal, and the other cairo terminals (`wxt` and `pdfcairo`) use [fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html).

With this, you must only create a file `~/.fonts.conf` with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
 <dir>~/fonts</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

and thats it. (Possibly you must check the available font names with e.g. `fc-list | grep $HOME/fonts`, but usually the font file names are self-explanatory). Then use e.g.

```
set terminal pngcairo font 'DroidSerif'
```

(Tested here with gnuplot 4.6.4)